# Which object HashSet is deserialised into in TypeScript?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I got an ASP.NET Core .NET 5 Angular SPA.

The EF proxy class with navigation property:

```
public partial class Parent
...
public virtual HashSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
```

How do I "correctly" declare `Children` property in TypeScript?

I tried array [] and Set but couldnt get it work.

```
interface Child {
  id: number; ...
}

interface Parent {
  id: number; ...
  children: Child[];
}
```

the JSON in browser (regardles Set or array TS type) is same:

```
[{
        "$id": "1",
        "id": 1,
        ...
            "parent": {
                "$id": "3",
                "$values": [{"$ref": "1"}]
            }
        },
        "children": {
            "$id": "4",
            "$values": [{
                    "$id": "5",
                    "id": 1,
            ...
```

in HTML I try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of parents[0].children | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>

outputs:

$id:4
$values:[object Object]
```

But this one outputs nothing:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of parents[0].children[0] | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Sequentially the following outputs nothing too (**this is actually why I am asking - how to get the `children` property work**):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of parents[0].children">
  {{item.id}}:{{item.name}}
</div>
```

I mean this is pretty basic scenario. EF object with navigation property needs to be displayed in the UI.
However I cant find what exactly needs to be done.

I would like a simple answer on - what is the correct type for navigation property `children` in TypeScript should be?

*Note: I have these $id, $values because I have to handle circular references in the EF classes*

**EDIT:** once I try `this.parents[0].children[0]` in Immediate window at run-time it says `undefined`:

```
this.parents[0]
Object {$id: "1", id: 1,…}
    $id: "1"
    id: 1
    ...
    children: Object {$id: "4", $values: Array(1)}

this.parents[0].children
Object {$id: "4", $values: Array(1)}
    $id: "4"
    $values: Array(1) [Object]
    __proto__: Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}

this.parents[0].children[0]
undefined
```

**EDIT2**: Once I introduced "fake" property `children_ts: Child[]` which is on server side is simply `Children_ts = Children.ToArray();` - everything started to work.. So I think its a bug and the front-end cannot work with references in JSON (eg `$values`)

Comment: AFAIK, JSON knows nothing about sets and what not, it's all arrays, so you deserialize into array. Just print the entire object after json-deserialization in typescript to see the structure. It might also be easier to do it in typescript rather than html so you have IntelliSense (if using VS/VS Code)

Comment: idk how to "print" objects. in VS i can see fields alright in intellisense if i type `this.parents[0].children[0] ...` (PS of course intellisense  would  work - it uses the interfaces - it doesnt know if data not there yet)

Comment: TypeScript erases all types in the transpilation process so the type declaration is not the cause for your problem. As suggested above, try to `console.log()` the object you received in the client (after calling `JSON.parse()` on the response), and make sure it is correct

Comment: I got into the object in Immediate Window - please see the edit. It says .. Array(1) but once I try to access children[0] it says undefined

Comment: Children is an object. The array is inside children.$values.

Comment: yeah I actually tried that as the very first thing.. but i did `children.values[0]` and it returned nothing.. I didnt realise you can use $values[0] .. you should write it as an answer.. but still I think its a bug because any dev would expect an array not a cryptic object with some $values